# How to bring a post up

Tags: discussion

Let's say that there is a question which hasn't received any answers after the question was asked and there is no duplicate questions. If the OP is not me how to bring that post up?

Comment: You mean, attract attention to a post ?  Easiest method is to set bounty on it, cheapest is 50 rep points

Comment: @Serg yes, is that the only thing except editing?

Comment: Technically speaking, yes, that's the only way. Editing a post tells the system that there is "activity" on the question, so it will go to front page, but it will stay there for limited time, maybe 30 minutes or an hour, depending on the amountof activity on the site in general.  Setting bounty will put it into "featured" tab for a week.  Which question are we talking about specifically here ? Maybe you can provide a link here and people will look into it. There's a "share" option below each question, click that, and copy the link here

Comment: I wanted an answer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/786446/360794) question, because it happened to me today, so I tried to edit it somehow to bring it up for a while, actually there was no intention or option to edit it for my knowledge, so the edit was rejected.  I fixed the problem trying so many things on the terminal, but that question forced me to ask this. Thanks @Serg

Comment: is your issue exactly the same as described in the question ? Did you also install a kernel and clock disappeared ?   ( I think it's not related, but if we are to bring attention to this question, people will probably focus on kernel as important factor, and it will affect how people answer )

Comment: @Serg Actually not exactly same, I did nothing knowingly directly related to the kernal but I was looking for an answer, after reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-applet-from-top-unity-panel?rq=1) and trying those things didn't work. So I wanted an answer to that previous one. :)

Comment: OK . . . in such cases, usually, it's OK to ask a new question and indicate in **bold** that the answers for that previous question didn't work. If you don't get an answer on it within couple days, let me know, and i will put a bounty on it

Comment: Thank you @Serg I will ask my question soon. :)

Comment: @Serg more than bolding stuff, what's important is indicating how those answers didn't work. It maybe that something changed and the error (if any) would be important in figuring out what. A person who just says "I tried **all the methods and nothing worked**" just comes across as a lazy liar.

Answer (score 21):

You could *improve it*, but these improvements need to be substantial and preserve the spirit of the question. Don't bump to bump

Occasionally "community" bumps up questions with no love - but this is random and automatic.

Posting a bounty's the preferred way, as Serg suggested.

Or you could answer the question ;)